# Como hago para cambiar de bloque? Unity 3D c#

Tags: c#, unity, 3d

Tengo el siguiente codigo:

using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class BuildSystem : MonoBehaviour {
    RaycastHit hit;
    Ray ray;
    Vector3 Paredposition;

```
public int elevacion;
public Transform CuboObjeto, Cubo, Cubo2;
public LayerMask layer;

public void Boton1(){
coso ();
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
            Instantiate (Cubo, CuboObjeto.position, CuboObjeto.rotation);

    }
}
public void Boton2(){
    coso ();
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
    Instantiate (Cubo2, CuboObjeto.position, CuboObjeto.rotation);
}
}
    void coso(){
    ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);
    if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 5, layer)){
        Paredposition = hit.point;
            Paredposition.y = 0f;
        CuboObjeto.position = Paredposition;
    }
    }
```

}

Lo que trato de hacer ahi es que al apretar un boton cambie a lo que corresponde

Tengo 2 botones, una para que aparezca negro y otro azul

Entonces que al apretar por ejemplo, negro, que yo pueda poner solo ese bloque 
y si luego toco blue, que pueda poner solo el azul, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si lo que deseas hacer es seleccionar el cubo que vas a instanciar cuando presionas un boton y posicionarlo en el mundo cuando das click puedes usar algo como esto

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class BuildSystem : MonoBehaviour {
RaycastHit hit;
Ray ray;
Vector3 Paredposition;

public int elevacion;
public Transform CuboObjeto, Cubo, Cubo2;
public LayerMask layer;

private Transform currentCube;

void Update()
{
    coso();
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
        Instantiate (currentCube, CuboObjeto.position, CuboObjeto.rotation);
    }
}

public void Boton1(){
    currentCube = Cubo;
}
public void Boton2(){
    currentCube = Cubo2;
}
void coso()
{
    ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);
    if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 5, layer)){
        Paredposition = hit.point;
        Paredposition.y = 0f;
        CuboObjeto.position = Paredposition;
    }
}
}
```

Espero que te haya servido de ayuda